# How to change the font style for Rust primitive types in SublimeText 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, rust

Right now types like i32 etc. are being shown as Italics.

I wish to avoid that, but the only Rust preferences I see are in compiled form in ~/Library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit your color scheme to change the syntax highlighting. Look for the scope `storage` or `storage.type` and remove the `italic` setting. [This resource](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com) is great for editing color schemes. If you're using Monokai, it comes up automatically. If not, click the `Gallery` button and select the color scheme you're using.